# get contact title visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lookup, contact

I have a visualforce page, related to the Opportunity Object.
There is a  lookup field (Influencer1__c), which looksup to the Contact object, name. How can i create another field to show the contacts title?

```
<td valign="top" width="120"  bgcolor="#DCE1E9"><apex:outputField value="{!StrategicSales__c.Influencer1__c}" >
```

Comment: (1) what's the relationship between `Opportunity` and `Strategic_Sales__c` ?  (2) and is the VF page using the Opportunity StandardController with or without a controller extension? Or is it a custom controller (not an extension)?

Comment: opportunity standardcontroller

Comment: I set up a master child rel from strategic sales to opportunity

Comment: (1) Strategic Sales is master to Oppo detail?  (2) Strategic Sales has lookup to Contact? Or Oppo has lookup to Contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a contact is parent here, you can display Contact fields by using ( __r ) relationship.

For example, the Title field of contact can be display on opportunity as, (Object (Object_Instance).Influencer1__r.Title

And you need to query these fields in apex method by using similar notation.

Comment: Opportunity is the related object, so i didn't thinks this would work, but it does, thank you.